# Twilio's TwilioRestClient SendSmsMessage returns null

Tags: c#, mono, amazon-ec2, twilio, restsharp

I have everything working locally, but when I test Twilio's service on an Amazon EC2 Debian 6.0.6 server running Mono 2.10.9, I find that sending SMS messages no longer works. I believe the problem lies somewhere in the server configuration, as I am using the latest Twilio (3.5.6), RestSharp (104.1) and JSON.NET (4.5.11) libraries, and I can guarantee that the variables used in the following method call are not empty at runtime.

```
var client = new Twilio.TwilioRestClient("{my account number}", "{my account token}");
var smsMessage = client.SendSmsMessage("{my account phone number}", "{my mobile phone number}", "Hello World!");
```

Using ntop, I have seen that there are bytes being sent/received to/form this reqeuest, but the smsMessage result is still null. The SendSMSMessage function utilizes the RestSharp library, particularly the RestClient's Execute function, which invokes a Deserialize method and returns an IRestResponse in which the Data field is null in this case.

I have seen some indications online that the problem may lie in the deserialization process, but, as I've ensured I am using the latest version of JSON.NET, I am not sure what other steps to take here.

Do you have any suggestions on resolving the problem and do you suspect it is a code or server issue? Also do you have any advice, using Debian, how I might further debug this interaction, perhaps even to get the full byte response externally from the application?

Comment: Hmmm. Is it actually sending the message correctly? is it possible the request is causing a 400 bad request when you try it on your Debian instance?

Comment: Actually newer versions of RestSharp are not longer dependent on JSON.NET, and instead uses its own internal JSON deserializer.  The Twilio helper library does maintain a dependency on JSON.NET, but the only time its used is if the request returns a status code greater than 400.  

So I'd suggest starting to debug by figuring out what status code is being returned by Twilio.  If its greater than 400, then it could be that JSON.NET is having an issue deserializing the data.  Otherwise its more likely that RestSharps deserializer is having a problem.

Comment: ...I also assume that since you are running on Debian, that you're using Mono?  If thats the case I believe there are mono specific solution files for both RestSharp and Twilio.  You might consider pulling the source for both libraries and building new libraries using the Mono specific projects.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I am using Mono. In using precompiled libraries for Twilio, I am unable to see the response object, as it is null. But I will follow Devin's advice and build the libraries myself. That should allow me to debug the process remotely. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In debugging the RestSharp library, I discovered that the exception had to do with SSL and Mono's trusted certificates. The exception message I received is as follows:

```
Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
```

Following the instructions in the link below helped me to resolve the issue, particularly by 
executing the following and restarting mono.

```
certmgr -ssl https://api.twilio.com
```

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security